# Laravel bindings - how to use call() method?

Tags: laravel, binding, service-provider

Could you give some example of usage of Laravel binding `call()` method? Below you have Laravel Container Interface `call()` method.

```
/**
* Call the given Closure / class@method and inject its dependencies.
*
* @param  callable|string  $callback
* @param  array  $parameters
* @param  string|null  $defaultMethod
* @return mixed
*/
public function call($callback, array $parameters = [], $defaultMethod = null);
```

I guess to work with that this way:

```
$this->app->call('how_to_use_this_params')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I never used this method. I'd like to use dependency injection like this example: https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/controllers#dependency-injection-and-controllers. But my guess is that you do something like this: ```$service = $this->app->call(SomeService::class);```

Comment: I need full and wide Inversion of Controll (IoC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this years after...

Thanks for putting me on the path to find what i wanted and my guessing was true!

This is to make a call to an object method using dependency injection.

like:

```
class ...{
     public function methodName(Request $request){
         ...
     }
}
// this call will resolve the $request by IOC
app()->call([$object,'methodName']);
```